# Opening links in a new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got a lot of links (150+) in an `href` (here I can only post 2) and I want them to be opened in a new tab or window. I've got this piece of code that works, but before I add it to my website and before I add it to a lot of articles of mine (250+), I want to make sure the syntax of the code is 100% correct. Also, do I need the `<p>`?

```
<script> 
window.onload = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
         a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
} 
</script>

<div id="links">
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com/" >test</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com/" >test</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it will work, Just ensure your links put into the DIV with id is "links"

Comment: it does not matter if you remove ``<p>`` tag. If u want to separate them to two lines, then keep it

Comment: I do not think you need the <p> tags

Comment: Putting a <p> tag on every link will put each link on a new paragraph. You could use a <br/> tag aswell

Comment: I'd recommend you to use search and replace to add `target="_blank"` to your links in your source code (html/php files or in the DB) rather than using a client-side script (it adds to the load, some users might have JS disabled and in general it's not elegant). But if you have to do it this way, it's fine. `<p>`'s are not neccessary as others have said, but you also don't need to use them for the layout and neither you have to add <br> to separate them. You can use CSS `#links a { display: block; }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is fine, though I would flip it, first html, then the javascript (without the window.onload).

AN example to explain why: If you have a huge image and a slow connection the loading takes say 5 seconds. These 5 seconds all your anchors don't have the `target="_blank"` and if a user clicks they still leave your website.

**I would not use this method meself** (unless I have to) . 
If you use AJAX to load content with anchors, those anchors will not have the `target="_blank"` either. This will require a bit more advances problem solving. If you want some links to be ignored, you can't with the current code. There are more small problems that will pop up which are all to minor to sum up here, but in the end are all just very ennoying.

I recommend that you do not rely on this method. Just take some time and update the content. I assume you have that in a datase, just `FIND()` and `REPLACE()`. Make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the JavaScript code is fine. You don't need the `<p>` tag for every `<a>` element. If you remove  `<p>`, it doesn't matter if you don't have a specific style CSS for your `<p>` tag. I don't know what you are using with the `<a>` tag. Remember, the `<p>` defines a paragraph.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to loop through all of your elements:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('#links a').forEach(function(el, i) {
        el.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    });
});
```

Comment: We are looking for answers that provide insightful observations about the code in the question. Answers that consist of independent solutions with no justification do not constitute a code review, and may be removed.

Comment: This will apply to *all* `<a>` elements, while the original question only applies to those under `getElementById('links')`

Comment: added a small fix.